# Is the Elite Soldier Pack available with all pre-orders?

Tags: steam, xcom-enemy-unknown

On Steam if you pre-purchase XCOM: Enemy Unknown you get something described as an "Elite Soldier Pack":

> The Elite Soldier Pack will provide the ultimate tools for soldier customization in XCOM: Enemy Unknown, including:
>
> **Classic XCOM Soldier**
>
> Players will instantly receive a new recruit in their barracks inspired by the original X-COM: UFO Defense. The iconic soldier with the blonde, flattop hairstyle will return fully modernized.
>
> **Soldier Deco packs**
>
> Players can customize their soldier with several aesthetic upgrades to armor suits, including the new Hyperion and Reaper soldier armor kits.
>
> **Complete color customization**
>
> A variety of colors and tints for all armor sets in the game allow players complete control to customize their squad’s look.

Is this pre-order bundle exclusive to Steam or is it possible to get this pre-order bonus (or similar) from other digital retailers?

If not, are there any other pre-order bundles worth consideration?

Comment: Voting to close as this question will only apply to a narrow window in time.

Comment: @DaveDuPlantis then we'll close it once the narrow window in time closes.

Comment: It could still be useful after the game launches if people see the pre-order content and wonder if they can unlock it somehow.

Comment: There is an [official answer](http://forums.2kgames.com/showthread.php?124998-The-Official-Preorder-Information-Thread!) to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the various other websites that allow you to pre-order XCOM: Enemy Unknown, the 'Elite Solider Pack DLC' appears to be a standard pre-order bonus for everywhere you can get the game.

The Steam pre-order bonuses (Team Fortress 2 items and potentially a free copy of Civilization V) are Steam specific, so not available anywhere else.

Since the game's release, the Elite Soldier Pack has been [released on Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/209811/) as a separate DLC, so those that didn't pre-order XCOM: Enemy Unknown can still get the Elite Soldier Pack by alternative means.